# Electromagnetic tensor in the Reissner Nordström metric

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, maxwell-equations

At [scholarpedia.org/article/Kerr-Newman_metric](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Kerr-Newman_metric) it is stated that, I quote:

[image: source]

but since $F_{\mu \nu}=\frac{\partial A_{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}-\frac{\partial A_{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}$, where does the $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator come from? I only get $\pm Q/r^2$:

[image: calculation]

so to me it looks like a mistake in the source, but since the authors are reputable, why is there a $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I am equally confused by this. Note that the coordinates being used are $u,r,\theta,\phi$ and not $t,r,\theta,\phi$. But I don’t see how this explains the $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I am aware of, but not familiar with, the tetrad formalism. I have the feeling that $F_{\mu\nu}$ is being expressed not in $u,r,\theta,\phi$ coordinates but in the $\ell,n,m,\bar{m}$ tetrad. The $\sqrt 2$ first appears in the tetrad.

Comment: I also don't know much about tetrad formalisms, but shouldn't $A_{\mu}$, which is in the same line, then also be expressed in that tetrad? If there is an $F_{\mu \nu}$ right next to an $A_{\mu}$ one would assume that $F_{\mu \nu}$ is derived by summing up $A_{\mu}$ like it is always done....

Comment: I agree that $A_\mu$ and $F_{\mu\nu}$ are both presumably using the $\ell, n,m,\bar m$ tetrad, but I’m not sure what $\partial_\mu$ means when using this tetrad. I suspect the resolution lies there.

Comment: You mean the $Q/r$ is not differentiated by $r$, but $r$ is a function of the tetrad coordinates and it is differentiated by them rather than by $r$? That would make sense, somehow, although the authors could have explained that better, for example by explicitely writing $Q/r(l,n,m,\bar{m})$ or something. Nevertheless, I'm relieved that the regular tensor is then without the $\sqrt{2}$ and I have no mistake there.

Comment: My guess is that $\partial_\mu$ is a directional derivative along the $\mu$-th basis vector of the tetrad, or something like that. The article seems to assume familiarity with the tetrad formalism. Explaining that formalism is not really the point of the article.